# BigIP F5 - How to - TMSH list pool members connection stats for an FQDN member?

Tags: f5, big-ip, tmsh

I have a pool that contains 2 members and 2 auto-generated FQDN members; e.g.

- Server01.domain.org
- Server02.domain.org
- _auto_104.1.1.1
- _auto_104.1.1.2

Where _auto_104.1.1.1 is linked to Server01.domain.org and the other is linked to 02.

If I want to see the connection stats for node Server01.domain.org - I notice the stats are only connected against _auto_104.1.1.1.

So how can I use TMSH to query Server01 connection stats?

Trying this;

```
tmsh list /ltm pool /Common/{{ pool_name }} all-properties
```

And get all member info, but no way to query Server01 and get the relevant '*auto*' nodes connection details?

I hope that makes sense!  Let me know if I'm misunderstanding any of this, as it would really help.

Thank you in advance.